# プロジェクトのバージョンを外部ファイルに定義する

Tags: c#, visual-studio

visual stdioでファイルバージョンとアセンブリバージョンを複数のプロジェクトに対して同じ値をつけるため、XMLファイルに値を定義してビルド時に読み込めればと考えています。
ビルド時のイベントはどのように捕まえれば良いのでしょうか。もしくは複数のプロジェクトに対して同じバージョンをつける方法は他にあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C#には[T4 テキストテンプレート](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2017)が用意されています。これを使うとC#コードを用いてC#コードが生成できます。更に[ビルドプロセスでのコード生成](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process?view=vs-2017)を実行する方法が提供されています。

後はXMLファイルから読み込み`AssemblyInfo.cs`相当のコードを生成すればいいかと思います。